# ERROR using ST_AsGeoJSON with PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgis

When I try to run the following command:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)
```

I get the following Error message:

```
HINT: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I got this Error message after I made a Backup of my DB and then restored it on a locally hosted new one. 
Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? I browsed the web and found out that a possible solution would be to run the "postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql file". (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/postgis-users/qrk4FD-k5H8)
But I have no clue what that is and where I can find this file (since I am very new to SQL and PostGIS).

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but the_geom is of type geometry? Also, can you see the ST_AsGeoJSON function if you look in pgAdmin -- it will by default be in the public schema -- or run \df ST_AsGeoJSON from a psql prompt. There should be four versions, if you have it installed properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that due to the restore you now have ambiguous functions called "ST_AsGeoJSON". You can run the following query to check:

```
select * from pg_proc where proname = 'st_asgeojson'
```

In a clean install, that should return you five rows. Bet you get more...

The solution is indeed to run the  "postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql" file. That is a file containing a list of SQL commands which cleans up things like the errant st_asGeoJSON functions. On Windows it's in the "share/contrib/postgis-[version]" directory under your postgresql installation. In my case, the full path is "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share\contrib\postgis-2.1\postgis_upgrade_21_minor.sql" - your path might be different depending on your OS and the Postgresql and Postgis version you're running.

If you're using PGAdmin, you can connect to your database and open an SQL window. Open that sql file and you can either run the whole thing, or scroll to the bottom, highlight the commands beginning "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson" and just run those.

Execute "select * from pg_proc where proname = 'st_asgeojson'" again, to see if it's made a difference.

Good luck!

[EDIT] Here are the SQL commands to drop the functions, copied from the .sql file if you have difficulty finding it.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(geometry); -- this one changed to use default args 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(geography); -- this one changed to use default args 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(geometry,int4); -- this one changed to use default args 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(geography,int4); -- this one changed to use default args 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(int4,geometry); -- this one changed to use default args
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(int4,geography); -- this one changed to use default args
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(int4,geometry,int4); -- this one changed to use default args
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ST_AsGeoJson(int4,geography,int4); -- this one changed to use default args
```

Comment: Indeed, I have 13 function when I run your command:
http://martinsiklar.com/st_geojson13.png

But I still dont really know how to get rid of them. I cant find the "postgis_upgrade_21_minor.sql - File". 
I figured out that in pgAdmin I can simply click on Functions and the see all 1k++ functions installed and by right clicking I can delete them. But how do I know which one, is the right one and which one is the wrong one?

Comment: If you have Windows, you could use Windows search to try to find the sql file. However, I'll edit my reply to add the commands to drop the functions.

Comment: When I run pgsql as my main user, I see 13 rows, but it won't let me drop the function since I'm not the owner. However, when I run as postgres user, there are only 5 rows and the drop commands return function does not exist. Suggestions??